# Error al mostrar resultados con PHP y Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Tengo una lista de notas que se tienen que mostrar de izquierda a derecha. Buscando llego a utilizar `List group` de Bootstrap.

Tengo el script que muestra la lista que es muy simple:

```
<?php
$ls = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tareas");
while ($row = $ls->fetch()) {
?>

<?=$row['tareacode'];?> // para usar en el codigo html
```

Leo que cada lista tiene que tener un `id` distinto, es por eso que cada tarea tiene un codigo y asi poder utilizar el `List group`. Pero al cerrar `while` no me muestra los resultados como deberia. Rompre el orden del html y todo se ve mal.

Me pueden ayudar a resolverlo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<title>Listado</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
  <?php
  $ls = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tareas");
  while ($row = $ls->fetch()) {
  ?>
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="<?=$row['tareacode'];?>" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">
<?=$row['titulo'];?>
<?=$row['descrip'];?>
<?=$row['facha'];?>
</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="<?=$row['tareacode'];?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
<?=$row['titulo'];?>
<?=$row['descrip'];?>
<?=$row['facha'];?>
</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">Resultado Dos</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">Resultado Tres</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">Resultado Cuatro</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
} // cierre del while
?>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código donde implementas ese while al html?

Comment: Esta arriba, es una consulta. No se bien en donde colocarlo por eso puse todo por separado

Comment: No queda claro qué es lo que esta mostrando mal, podrías indicarnos que es lo que buscas específicamente?

Comment: Ahi modifique lo que seria el `html` e inserte el codigo `php`. El codigo `php` hace bucle en donde me muestra los datos de la base de datos, bien, se podrian mostrar como una lista normal, pero me piden que se vea de forma tal que al hacer click en una tarea, en el lado derecho se muestre el resultado

Comment: @previant De acuerdo, con este último comentario se entiende bien lo que quieres. ¿Podrías decir que campos tiene la tabla tareas para poder adecuar el código a tus necesidades?

Comment: Hice la modificacion de los campor de las notas: `<?=$row['titulo'];?>`, `<?=$row['descrip'];?>`, `<?=$row['facha'];?>`... en el lado derecho la descripción se vera toda la nota completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la nueva información que has dado yo utilizaría un código similar a este (te aviso que lo he editado en la página a mano por lo que puede haber algún fallo de sintaxis):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<title>Listado</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <?php
  $ls = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tareas");
  $resultados = $ls ->fecthAll()

  foreach($resultados as $res) :?>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="<?=$row['tareacode'];?>" data-toggle="list" href="#list-<?=$row['tareacode'];?>" role="tab" aria-controls="home">
<?=$row['titulo'];?>
</a>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <?php foreach($resultados as $res) :?>
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="<?=$row['tareacode'];?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-<?=$row['tareacode'];?>">
<?=$row['descrip'];?>
<?=$row['facha'];?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Mikel. Me esta pasando lo mismo que cuando uso `while`, lista de un lado y del otro, pero no funciona el script. Sera algo de jquery o javascript?

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo. Cambie las medidas de las columnas y se ve bien. Gracias!